# bullet physics: to move rigid body to particular point

Tags: physics, bulletphysics, kinematics

I am new to bullet physics and my usecase is like 
I Know start position (x1 ,y1)and end position (x2,y2) .now by applying some force at the center of rigid body,it should move to end position (x2,y2) and then because of gravity it should fall  (similar to kinematics reach maximum position by a projectile motion and falls down due to gravity).

I am using as below body->applyCentralForce(force);
But it was not reaching expected or end poistion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried body->setLinearVelocity(velocity); instead of body->applyCentralForce(force); and everything works as expected.

Comment: both should work actually ... keep in mind the forces are reset to 0 in every simulation step, hence you need to keep apply forces in each cycle to keep the movement up